# How to fix internal service error in microsoft azure when deleting vhd/disk?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, internal-storage, vhd

I'd like to delete my storage account by getting in the Virtual Machine ---> Disk

But when I delete the disk it says "Internal Service Error"!
[Internal Service Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUhKE.png)

Comment: After you checked that you didn't try to commit suicide, you'll want to look at [this web page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/faq/) next.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1)  Check if the disk is attached to a VM,
        Get-AzureDisk | Where-Object {$_.AttachedTo -eq $null} | Format-Table -auto "DiskName"
         Make sure that the VHDs they want to delete are included in this list.

2)  If the disks are listed in the result from step #1, continue with deleting the VHDs using this command,
Remove-AzureDisk -DiskName  -DeleteVHD
            Replace  with the DiskName that shows up in the list from first command.

3)  If VHD is not listed in step #1, it means it is still attached to a VM. If that’s the case, then they must detach the disk from the VM and delete VHD.
Get-AzureVM  –Name  | Get-AzureDataDisk
             Replace  ,  with corresponding values.
            This will provide them with the list of data disks attached to their VM along with the LUN number.

Get-AzureVM   –Name   | Remove-AzureDataDisk -LUN  -DeleteVHD     | Update-AzureVM
•   Replace  ,  and  with corresponding values. This command will also delete the corresponding VHD.

If you still have issues, please send an email to ascl@microsoft.com.